# Why functions are called methods in java?

Tags: java, methods

Why functions are called methods in java. I am not asking the difference between the two. Why Java community choose to name them methods. Is there any concrete reason behind this decision or it's just a name?
When i think of literal meaning as far as i could think function is related to internal working of some machine. Method is a way of working to achieve a goal(mathematical solution) or may be method is a way of implementing an Object.
Is that where it came from or i just missed the real picture?

Comment: Guess you should contact James Gosling :)

Comment: As i have already mentioned in my question that i am not asking for difference between the two.

Comment: It becomes a lot more clear if you consider languages other than Java, particularly "functional" languages.  Functions are more stateless in that they independently operate on what's given to them whereas methods are functionality exposed by a particular stateful object.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey: Actually, you are, basically. The terms mean different things. The correct term for what Java has is "method", for the reasons given in the answer to that question. So that's the term they used.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey: If you're not asking for the difference between the two, then what *are* you asking?  If you know the difference (which, admittedly, I didn't until recently) then what is unclear?

Comment: Yes I bet i should Balwinder Singh.

Comment: Functions are not called methods in java. Your premise is wrong because you don't know what the differences between the two are.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Ah, good point! Particularly now that Java has functions, as of Java 8. :-) (At least, I don't *think* it did before that...)

Comment: @David:I am asking why Java community name them methods why didn't them them 'procedure' or something else.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey: Because they are methods.  For the same reason they called variables "variables."  Because that's what they are.

Comment: @David: So all you are saying is that they are just names? As far as i know Java has a very big community and they don't take any single decision so lightly and please don't down vote as i am newbie in java. I am just eager to learn :)

Comment: @Mr.Pandey: I'm saying that the words "function" and "method" in this context have specific meanings.  Java chose to call them "methods" because they fit the already-existing meaning of that word.  Had they called them "functions" they would be introduced confusion because that word already has a different meaning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not in Java, it's an [OOP name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29).

In sort, it defines part of the behavior of an instance of an object, not a general operation.

Answer (score 1):

Every language has it's own syntax to differentiate from others. As for your question

Functions existence is independent.

Methods do not as they are created within the class.

Answer (score 1):

## Why functions are called methods in java?

1. A method is on an object.
2. A function is independent of an object.
3. For Java, there are only methods.
4. For C, there are only functions.

For C++ it would depend on whether or not you're in a class.

`In languages such as C++, functions are bits of code that will perform a particular action - but are not associated with an object. functions that are to do with an object are called methods. in java all functions are methods as they are all to do with objects.`

Comment: Well, IMHO static methods are closer to functions in this respect. But I mostly agree with you.